# C++11 template alias for a method callback

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias, typedef

Is it possible to use C++11 template aliases for method callbacks?

I have a templated method that takes a method callback as one of its input parameters, e.g.:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    template <typename OtherClass, typename T>
    void Bar(void (OtherClass::*callback)(T *));
};
```

I would like to be able to rewrite the Bar() prototype so that it uses a type since I will be using the same type in several places in the implementation. I tried using the new C++11 alias below but it did not work.

```
class Foo {
  public:
     // This does not work
     template <typename OtherClass, typename T>
     using Callback = void (OtherClass::*)(T *object);

     void Bar(Callback callback);
};
```

What am I missing? I could not find an example of how this would work on several of my favorite C++11 reference web sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not work that way. This:

```
template <typename OtherClass, typename T>
using Callback = void (OtherClass::*)(T *object);
```

Is declaring an alias template, which means you have to *instantiate* `Callback` in order to get a type. For instance:

```
Callback<C, int>
```

Will resolve into:

```
void (C::*)(int*)
```

So your member should be declared this way:

```
template<typename OC, typename T>
void Bar(Callback<OC, T> callback);
```

Comment: What's the right way to invoke the callback?

when I call it like this:

instance->*callback(parameter);

I get the following error:

callback.cpp:12:21: error: called object type 'Callback<Object, int>' (aka 'void (Object::*)(int *)') is not a function or function pointer
         instance->*callback(&value);

This is with clang 3.1. gcc 4.8 gives me a similar error.

Thanks!

Comment: @user2180977: Have you tried putting parentheses around `instance->*callback`? Like this: `(instance->*callback)(parameter);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the template parameters:

```
template <typename U, typename T>
void Bar(Callback<U, T> callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The Bar() method needs to be templated as well.

This works:

```
class Foo {
  public:
     template <typename OtherClass, typename T>
     using Callback = void (OtherClass::*)(T *object);

     template <typename OtherClass, typename T>
     void Bar(Callback<OtherClass, T> callback);
};
```